# Android ListView Issue

Tags: android, listview

I have an issue where some devices are not able to select a listview item and I can't seem to work out what is wrong in the code - selecting a listview item works fine on my device and on the emulator. I have checked the focus, but that does not appear to be the issue. Anyone have any ideas?

public class GroupListFragment extends ListFragment

```
  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    Group group = (Group) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(group);
  }
```

public class GroupListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GroupListFragment.Callbacks

```
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(Group group) {

      if (twoPaneLayout) {
        // seems to work fine
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putLong(GroupDetailFragment.GROUP_ITEM_ID, group.getId());

        GroupDetailFragment fragment = new GroupDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        replaceDetailPane(fragment);
      } else {
        // does not work on some mobile devices
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, GroupDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(GroupDetailFragment.GROUP_ITEM_ID, group.getId());

        startActivity(detailIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
      }

  }
```

List view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_group_background" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_group_item_background"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_group_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="User 22222222222222222222123456789012345"
                android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_group_item_header_text"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_group_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Group status..."
                android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_group_item_status_text"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_group_callout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/callout_background"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="new"
            android:textColor="@drawable/callout_text"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item_group_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_group_toolbar_background"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_item_group_edit"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_item_group_edit_background"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_item_group_delete"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/list_item_group_delete_background"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see your `OnItemClickListener`? Also, when you say that it doesn't work, what does that mean? Just that the `OnItemClickListener` fails to fire? What should be happening that doesn't?

Comment: I have updated the main comment. The issue is when the user clicks the list item on a mobile device it does not fire the 'onListItemClick' method and it does not load the detail activity. But, I'm not sure why the 'onListItemClick' is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the code to the below and it is now working.

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Group group = (Group) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(group);
      }
    });
  }
```

I am not sure why moving the click listener to the onStart() method has worked, but it has.